# ExecuteQuery: Java out of Heap Space

Tags: java, sql, executequery

I am using ExecuteQuery [(www.executequery.org](http://www.executequery.org)) to connect to a remote Oracle DB. I have received an .sql-file that I'm supposed to run on this DB. But I cannot even load this file into ExecuteQuery, because apparently it's too big: I get a Java Exception, saying that the Java Heap Space is too small.

I know how to specify Java Heap Size when executing a Java program from the console. But how can I tell ExecuteQuery to increase the heap? Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: You're asking at the wrong place. Go to their [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/executequery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I solved it with a little workaround: Go to something like

```
Menu -> Database -> execute SQL script
```

Like this,  the heap space seems not to be affected.

Comment: You're right, this way the script can be loaded. Now only the problem with the connection resides, but thats another issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your sql is too large. Probably what you see is just the symptom of another error. Have you tried raising the heap when starting the program? If yes, you should try to debug the program and see if your running into an expensive loop or similar. Maybe it is even a bug inExecuteQuery - try asking in their google group.

I do not think there is any possibility nor need for allocating memory from within the app.

Comment: I raised the heap via the eq.l4j.ini file to 1 GB (apparently my VM is not able to handle more than that). This was sufficient to load the file into ExecuteQuery, but now it's taking ages to getting a connection to the DB ... But as you said, I will ask EQ via their Google group.